# Regularity of stochastic heat equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

For the heat equation:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \Delta u + \zeta(t,x)$$

where $u:\mathbb{R}^{+}\times \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\zeta$ is a space-time white noise.

I'm wondering how to understanding the following words:

''We can ‘trade’ space-regularity against time-regularity at a cost of one time derivative for two space derivatives.''

I want an example to understand these words. Could you please show me some examples?

Answer (score 0):

The presence of noise allows to exchange ("trade") time regularity for space regularity. For a simple example, consider the map
$$(t,x)\mapsto \int_0^t b(s,x+W_s)\,ds,$$
with Gaussian noise $W_s$. If without the noise the map is $C_t^1C_x^0$, with the noise it becomes $C_t^0 C_x^1$, so the improvement of space regularity is obtained at the cost of loss of time regularity. See these [lecture notes](https://www.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/galeati/delft_regularisation_averaging.pdf) (pages 14+15).

In the case of the stochastic heat equation, the noise converts $C_t^{1/2}C_x^0$ regularity into $C_t^{1/4}C_x^{1/2}$ regularity, at a "rate of two powers of space to one power of time". This is derived in section 5.1 of these [notes](https://www.hairer.org/SPDEs.pdf). The heuristics for the two-to-one conversion rate is based on dimensional analysis: The heat equation $u_t=Du_{xx}$ has one dimensionfull coefficient $D$ with dimensions length$^2$/time. This allows the conversion of $p$ powers of space into $q$ powers of time at a ratio $p:q=2:1$.

Comment: "If without the noise the map is $C_t^1C_x^0$, with the noise it becomes $C_t^0 C_x^1$" -- (i) What map? $b$? (ii) What do you mean by "it becomes"? (iii) Why?

Comment: "In the case of the [stochastic heat equation](https://www.hairer.org/SPDEs.pdf)" -- What specific statement in Hairer's notes are you referring here to?

Comment: You have just found "where the quote in the OP comes from". However, the question was to explain why this is true.